# How to export openERP invoices to Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, export

I successfully connected openERP to Magento. Now I am getting all the orders in openERP as sales orders, which we added in Mageno. Now I created invoices for that orders but how to export that invoices to Magento?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to connect with Magento :

https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/magentoerpconnect/

Comment: I used that connector only it is working fine, but my question is how to export invoices of sales orders from opnERP to Magento?